# Facing issue with rich-notify tag

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Is it possible to disable the main screen operations while showing the success message using 
**rich:notify**  tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "main screen operations"?

Comment: With stock Richfaces components, I don't think so. Not without creative styling of an `<a4j:outputPanel/>` or using a `<rich:popupPanel/>` as your notification component